Is it normal for postfix to be status active(exited)?
Is it normal for postfix status to be active(exited)? My mail server is having relay issues and I'm not sure about the status active(exited)

Yes, this is normal. If you want help, posting your log files would be more helpful.

the postfix.service unit is just a placeholder that doesn't do anything by itself. relevant would be the instance unit(s) (postfix@-.service, possibly more like that. list them with systemctl list-units -t service |grep postfix.). They should be running.
